# Sub or Function not defined issue

Tags: vba, excel

I have an issue with excel VBA, as I am trying to use the following code and I keep on receiving the compiler error mentioned in the title.

I made the code through mixing and matching and some work of my own by it is not high quality and I do not even know if the code would even work.

I have tried to add the references but that did not work, and I do not know what part of the code exactly is the problem here.

Appreciate the help in advance.

```
    Sub Emails_Verifier()
     Dim i As Integer
       Dim IE As Object
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    IE.Visible = True
    IE.Navigate "website"
    Application.StatusBar = "Submitting"
        While IE.Busy
            DoEvents
        Wend
    For i = 2 To lastRow
           IE.Document.getElementById("id").Value = cell(i, 7)
           IE.Document.getElementById("Submit").Click
        Application.StatusBar = "Form Submitted"
        IE.Document.getElementsByName ("elementID")
        If InStr(elm.innerText, "E-mail address") Then
            Set cell(i, 14) = elm.innerText
        End If
        Next i
        IE.Quit
    Set IE = Nothing
    End Sub
```

Comment: Go through your code line by line and find the problem. Enter the module and press f8 until it errors out. Then come back and tell us what the problem is. Also - your organization is somewhat sloppy; general practice is to indent within each "closed" set of arguments. ie: Your "For i = 2 loop" should be indented to the same degree as the "Next i" line.

Comment: Thank you, I will have this checked right away. And I know about the organization, I will have that fixed too, as I am still new in this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Nicolas is right with the `cells` part.

Another problem is you are trying access `elm` as object without initializing it. You've to first initialize it something like this way:

```
Sub Emails_Verifier()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim IE As Object
    Dim objCollection As Object

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    IE.Visible = True
    IE.Navigate "website"
    Application.StatusBar = "Submitting"
    While IE.Busy
        DoEvents
    Wend
    For i = 2 To lastRow
        IE.Document.getElementById("id").Value = cells(i, 7)
        IE.Document.getElementById("Submit").Click
        Application.StatusBar = "Form Submitted"
        Set objCollection = IE.Document.getElementsByName ("elementID")  '<---
        j = 0  '<---
        While j < objCollection.Length
            If InStr(objCollection(j).innerText, "E-mail address") Then
                Set cells(i, 14) = elm.innerText
            End If
            j = j + 1
        Wend
    Next i
    IE.Quit
    Set objCollection = Nothing
    Set IE = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for this, I did not know about this. I am using the as I am trying to get a result from the website tags text, which I noticed now that it does not work this way, as I need to get the exact text for the last td tag only. So I will try to find out what I can do..

Thanks again

Comment: "objCollection(j).innerText" should give you the text of the tag.

Answer (score 0):

Try this now:

```
Sub Emails_Verifier()

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim IE As Object

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    IE.Visible = True
    IE.Navigate "website"

    Application.StatusBar = "Submitting"

    While IE.Busy
        DoEvents
    Wend

    For i = 2 To lastRow

        IE.Document.getElementById("id").Value = Cells(i, 7)
        IE.Document.getElementById("Submit").Click
        Application.StatusBar = "Form Submitted"
        IE.Document.getElementsByName ("elementID")

        If InStr(elm.innerText, "E-mail address") Then
            Set Cells(i, 14) = elm.innerText
        End If

    Next i

    IE.Quit

    Set IE = Nothing

End Sub
```

The main error is using `cell` at the following line in your function:

```
IE.Document.getElementById("id").Value = cell(i, 7)
Set Cells(i, 14) = elm.innerText
```

I modified it to `Cells`.Actually,

It is not good. I suggested to use as `Sheets("sheetname").Cells(row, column)`.

Comment: This worked actually, Thank you! The code does not serve the purpose I want yet, but I will try to have this fixed on my own. 

Thanks Again